# smooth camera rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Ok im new to javascript and Unity so this is clearly a very noob beginner question.
Basically I have created a script that i place on my camera. Then when i select a model in the game it becomes the target of the camera script and im trying to make the camera smoothly turn to it. below is what im trying

in the update function i use raycast to catch a unit on the mouse click. this becomes the target variable in the script. it sets a bool to true then to follow target in the moveto function. but it only seems to move the camera if i keep the mouse left button pressed down on the unit. Im trying to select a unit then let the camera smoothly rotate to the unit.
Any ideas on this rookie mistake?

```
#pragma strict
var speed = 5.0;
var freeMovementTurnSpeed = 10.0;
var freeMovementForwardSpeed = 10.0;
var freeMovementVerticalSpeed = 10.0;
var maxHeight = 30;
var minHeight = 2;

var target : Transform;

var distance = 10.0;

var maxDistance = 50;
var minDistance = 10;

var xSpeed = 250.0;
var ySpeed = 120.0;

var yMinLimit = -20;
var yMaxLimit = 80;

private var x = 0.0;
private var y = 0.0;

// The distance in the x-z plane to the target
var followDistance = 30.0;
var maxDistanceDelta = 0.2;
var damping = 3.0;
var followTarget = false;
var smoothRotation ;
function Start () {
    var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    x = angles.y;
    y = angles.x;

    if(target){
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (rigidbody)
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
}

function LateUpdate () {
    if(target){
        if(followTarget){
            moveTo();
        }
        else{
            targetSelectedMovement();
        }
    }
    else {
        freeMovement();
    }


}

function moveTo(){

    //transform.LookAt (target);

    var currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position);

    //if (currentDistance<40){
        //followTarget = false;
    //}
    //else{

        smoothRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, smoothRotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
        print(target);
        //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,target.position,maxDistanceDelta);
    //}

}

function freeMovement(){
    var zPos = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * freeMovementForwardSpeed;
    var xPos = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * freeMovementTurnSpeed;
    var strafePos = Input.GetAxis("Strafe")* Time.deltaTime * freeMovementForwardSpeed;
    var vertPos = Input.GetAxis("GainVertical")* Time.deltaTime * freeMovementVerticalSpeed;

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire2")) {
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02;

        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        var rotation2 = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
        transform.rotation = rotation2;
    }
    else {
        transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*freeMovementTurnSpeed*Time.deltaTime, 0,Space.World);
    }
    if (vertPos > 0 && transform.position.y  > maxHeight){
        vertPos = 0;
    }
    else if(vertPos < 0 && transform.position.y < minHeight){
        vertPos = 0;
    }

    print(transform.position.y);
    transform.Translate(strafePos,vertPos,zPos);

}
function targetSelectedMovement() {
    if(Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d") ){

        x += (-Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) * xSpeed * 0.02;
        var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
        var currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position);

        var position = rotation * Vector3(0.0, 0.0, -currentDistance) + target.position;

        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
    }

    var zPos = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position);
    if(currentDistance < maxDistance && zPos < 0){
        transform.Translate(0, 0, zPos);
    }
    else if(currentDistance > minDistance && zPos > 0){
        transform.Translate(0, 0, zPos);
    }
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire2")) {
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02;

        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        var rotation2 = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
        var currentDistance2 = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position);

        var position2 = rotation2 * Vector3(0.0, 0.0, -currentDistance2) + target.position;

        transform.rotation = rotation2;
        transform.position = position2;
    }
}

static function ClampAngle (angle : float, min : float, max : float) {
    if (angle < -360)
        angle += 360;
    if (angle > 360)
        angle -= 360;
    return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
}

function Update () {

    var hit : RaycastHit;

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) {

        var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        // Cast a ray forward from our position for the specified distance
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit))
        {
            // Add a specified force to the Rigidbody component to the other GameObject
            if(hit.collider.tag == "Unit"){
                print("Selected " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);
                target = hit.collider.gameObject.transform;
                //transform.LookAt(target);
                followTarget = true;
            }
            else {
                target = null;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the whole script?  Yours looks fine and I tested it, works as advertised.

Comment: yup i just linked the full script. if that helps let me know coz im lost

Comment: I'll have to look when I get on my dev. machine but in the mean time try replacing Input.GetButton("Fire1") with Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1").  Just as a test, because looking at your code nothing jumps out at me.  GetButton is true as long as the button is held, in the past I have had issues with it incorrectly triggering just as the mouse moved off an object.

Comment: You my friend are a genius!! hard to believe that was what the issue was! wow ! very much appreciated i was going mad with that one. Im still not sure why exactly it wouldnt work the other way though. By all means create that as your answer and ill gladly accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:)

Answer pulled from my comments above:

"I'll have to look when I get on my dev. machine but in the mean time try replacing Input.GetButton("Fire1") with Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"). Just as a test, because looking at your code nothing jumps out at me. GetButton is true as long as the button is held, in the past I have had issues with it incorrectly triggering just as the mouse moved off an object."